# How to move to root ViewController on logout button click in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have one login page and once i logged in it will take me to a home page with `mkmapview` .On top left i have one menu button on click of that one left `slideview` will open .Here am using a library called `SlideNavigationController` for opening leftview. In that left view i have one logout button .When i click logout button i have to open my login page.
now when i click  on logout button it will slideout and go to home page not to login page.

please check my project structure in following image link

[screen image](http://postimg.org/image/pn1r4qu0z/)

This is my current code

```
- (IBAction)logout:(id)sender 
{
    HomeController *vieww=[[HomeController alloc]init];
    loginController *vie=[[loginController alloc]init];
    [[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance] popToRootAndSwitchToViewController:vie
                                                             withSlideOutAnimation:self.slideOutAnimationEnabled
                                                                     andCompletion:nil];
}
```

In this it will  show a screen like this instead of login screen
[device screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/ypx9cqa39/)

Please help

Comment: popToRootViewController didn't work?

Comment: Try to seperate login view from your navigationcontroller. Display it as a modal view when it's necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to go to root view controller when you click logout action

```
- (IBAction)logout:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get all ViewControllers in a NSArray after that you can back where you want with ObjectAtIndex value .

```
 NSArray *viewsArray = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
 UIViewController *chosenView = [viewsArray objectAtIndex:1];//set index where you want to go back
 [self.navigationController popToViewController:chosenView animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your `LoggedIn` detail in `NSUserDefaults`

And then Check  in `viewWillAppear` method of `HomeViewController`

You have to clear that `NSUserDefaults` on `Click` of `LogOut Button` and need to navigate `HomeViewController`

For example

You are storing `USER_ID` in `NSUserDefaults` at time of `LoggedIn` like following

> [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@“Your Value”
>   forKey:@"USER_ID"]; 
>   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

Now in `HomeViewController` in `viewWillAppear` method  put following check.

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"USER_ID"]){
    //User already logged in.
}else{
    // User is not logged in so need to show login page.
}
```

Clear `NSUserDefaults` in `LogOut Button Action` via following.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"USER_ID"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: i think u totally deviated from question,  problem is how can i navigate to login page from a slidernavigation side page

Comment: Hi Naveen,

What you are doing for showing loginViewController.?

You are presenting controller or Pushing to homeViewController after successful Login.?
If you are presenting from homeViewController then you can present LoginViewController from ViewWillAppear Method.

Comment: @NaveenKumar my answer is useful or not

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you

for many good reason write `goToLogin` method in your Appdelegate

```
 -(void)goToLogin
    {
        yourLoginViewController *objyourLoginViewController =[[yourLoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"yourLoginViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.objNavigationController =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:objyourLoginViewController];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.objNavigationController;
    }

- (IBAction)logout:(id)sender 
{

[(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate) goToLogin];
}
```

Comment: @NaveenKumar loginviewcontroller is your rootviewcontroller ??